# Convert Hex string to Byte Array for RSA Decryption

Tags: java, type-conversion, rsa, encryption, hexdump

I have a hex string after RSA encryption. When I convert it to a byte[], the RSA decryption gives javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Blocktype mismatch: 0

I am using this method for conversion (got it on Stack overflow itself)

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String data) {
    int k = 0;
    byte[] results = new byte[data.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length();) {
        results[k] = (byte) (Character.digit(data.charAt(i++), 16) << 4);
        results[k] += (byte) (Character.digit(data.charAt(i++), 16));
        k++;
    }
    return results;
}
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Your conversion looks good. I suppose your mistake is somewhere else. (By the way, instead of "got it on Stack Overflow itself", the proper way would be to link to the relevant question/answer.)

Comment: Can you post the relevant decryption section of the code?  Perhaps you're using `String.getBytes()` somewhere instead of this routine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encryption method requires the input to be a fixed-length; you're going to have to add padding to the required length in order to avoid this exception.  This size will depend on the key size.

EDIT: There is also a potential bug in your iteration of `data`:  If its length is not divisible by two then the second `i++` will cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  You are better off incrementing `i` by 2 in the `for` loop and using `[i]` and `[i+1]` when accessing the data:

```
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < data.length(); i += 2, k++)
{
    results[k] = (byte) (Character.digit(data.charAt(i), 16) << 4);
    results[k] += (byte) (Character.digit(data.charAt(i + 1), 16));
}
```

Comment: This is true; however, typically when you instantiate the cipher it chooses a padded transform by default, so there's no need to play with madding manually.  But it depends entirely on OPs code...

Comment: Your version of the code will give exactly the same IndexOutOfBoundsException. (It is more clear, though.)